# How to restart ssh and Samba after a temporary network disconnection?

Tags: ssh, debian, samba

I have a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)) connected to my home WiFi, which I primarily use as a Samba file server to access files on my other devices.

I occasionally have to reboot my WiFi router to fix issues, and I'm unable to re-connect to the Samba server once the network is back up and running. I'm also unable to ssh into the server. Restarting the Pi (by unplugging and replugging the power supply) fixes the issue, since I've setup Samba to start on system startup.

Do these services crash when there is no network connected? How can I fix this so that it auto-recovers/restarts these services once the Pi re-connects to the network?

Thanks!

Comment: Please reboot the  WiFi router so that the network connection on the RasPi fails afterwards. Then execute this command on the RasPi: `ip addr`, edit your question and paste the commands output into the question.

Comment: And while you're at it, check the status of your samba server after the router reboot. BTW, restarting the Pi by unplugging and replugging the power supply is not the greatest idea out there: you'll get a damaged filesystem one day.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart the servers. Get the network reconnected. Get the client system reconnected and you're done.